# SQL Joins Please help me the below

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data In two tables like below:

[image]

I need the third table output. I have used joins but it is not working. I have used rank also.

```
SELECT 
   a.requestinstancelogid AS requestinstancelogidIn, 
   a.requestinstanceid AS InRequestInstance, 
   a.requeststatuscdid AS Inrequeststatuscdid, 
   a.Addnldocsin, 
   b.requestinstancelogid AS requestinstancelogidOut, 
   b.requestinstanceid AS OutRequestInstance, 
   b.requeststatuscdid AS Outrequeststatuscdid, 
   b.AddnldocsOut, 
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.requestinstanceid ORDER BY a.requestinstancelogid) AS one, 
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.requestinstanceid ORDER BY b.requestinstancelogid) AS two
INTO 
   #tmp_MultipleAddnlDocsLender
FROM 
   #tmp_addnldocsin a
LEFT JOIN 
   #tmp_addnldocsout b ON a.requestinstanceid = b.requestinstanceid
WHERE 
   a.requestinstanceid = 164944
```

This query returns 6 records.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far and why it's not working.

Comment: And explain what is the logic that should be followed. The example has no logic.

Comment: Simply there are no matching rows in your first two tables so that they could result the third, unless you have some specific logic unknown to us till now.

Comment: I have updated my question. There is a matching column in both table requestinstanceidIn and requestinstanceidOut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i can see that you could produce these results is the following:

```
;WITH Table1CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY requestinstanceidin ORDER BY requestinstancelogid) AS rn
    FROM   Table1
), Table2CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY requestinstanceidout ORDER BY requestinstancelogid) AS rn
    FROM   Table2
)
SELECT * 
FROM   Table1CTE T1
       LEFT JOIN Table2CTE T2
           ON T1.requestinstanceidin = T2.requestinstanceidout 
              AND T1.rn= T2.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As far as I can tell, the same column in both is the `requestinstanceidout` (could hardly read it, please post text or code next time)

Based on the idea of the above is correct, you could have something like this:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
table1 a
LEFT JOIN table 2 b
ON a.requestinstanceidin = b.requestinstanceidout
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: But i need only 3 records which i have shown in the third table in the screen shot.

Comment: @user3619447 could you please post the 6 rows you are getting (I think it's the same as in your original query) in the OP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a cross/outer apply
like this

```
SELECT    
    a.requestinstancelogid AS requestinstancelogidIn, 
    a.requestinstanceid AS InRequestInstance, 
    a.requeststatuscdid AS Inrequeststatuscdid,
    a.Addnldocsin, 
    q.requestinstancelogid AS requestinstancelogidOut, 
    q.requestinstanceid AS OutRequestInstance, 
    q.requeststatuscdid AS Outrequeststatuscdid, 
    q.AddnldocsOut 
FROM #tmp_addnldocsin a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 
    b.requestinstancelogid AS requestinstancelogidOut, 
    b.requestinstanceid AS OutRequestInstance, 
    b.requeststatuscdid AS Outrequeststatuscdid, 
    b.AddnldocsOut 
    FROM #tmp_addnldocsout b 
    WHERE a.requestinstanceidin = b.requestinstanceidout 
    ORDER BY AddnIdocsOut DESC) q
WHERE 
   a.requestinstanceid = 164944
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
declare @request_instance_log_id_in table (
 [log]       [int]
 , [in]      [int]
 , [status]  [int]
 , [created] [datetime] default current_timestamp);
insert into @request_instance_log_id_in
        ([log],[in],[status])
values      (424593,164944,110),
        (424594,164944,110),
        (424595,164944,110);
declare @request_instance_log_id_out table (
[log]       [int]
, [out]     [int]
, [status]  [int]
, [created] [datetime] default current_timestamp);
insert into @request_instance_log_id_out
        ([log],[out],[status])
values      (424593,164944,112),
        (424594,164944,112);
select [request_instance_log_id_in].[log]        as [request_instance_log_id_in_log]
   , [request_instance_log_id_in].[in]       as [request_instance_log_id_in_in]
   , [request_instance_log_id_in].[status]   as [request_instance_log_id_in_status]
   , [request_instance_log_id_in].[created]  as [request_instance_log_id_in_created]
   , [request_instance_log_id_out].[log]     as [request_instance_log_id_out_log]
   , [request_instance_log_id_out].[out]     as [request_instance_log_id_out_out]
   , [request_instance_log_id_out].[status]  as [request_instance_log_id_out_status]
   , [request_instance_log_id_out].[created] as [request_instance_log_id_out_created]
from   @request_instance_log_id_in as [request_instance_log_id_in]
   left join @request_instance_log_id_out as [request_instance_log_id_out]
          on [request_instance_log_id_out].[log] = [request_instance_log_id_in].[log];
```

request_instance_log_id_in_log  request_instance_log_id_in_in   request_instance_log_id_in_status   request_instance_log_id_in_created  request_instance_log_id_out_log request_instance_log_id_out_out request_instance_log_id_out_status  request_instance_log_id_out_created
424593  164944  110 2014-09-02 08:55:01.107 424593  164944  112 2014-09-02 08:55:01.107
424594  164944  110 2014-09-02 08:55:01.107 424594  164944  112 2014-09-02 08:55:01.107
424595  164944  110 2014-09-02 08:55:01.107 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL